# Get url of uploaded file in firebase storage with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

i have a small mistake on my script,
im trying to upload file to firebase storage using vuejs, everything works except that the url is null,my script is a form of book value which contains, an id, titre, description,prix_d,pdf(is the file), pdf_url and the uploaded value that is script

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
import db from "./firebaseInit";
export default {
  name: "vendre",
  data : ()=>{
    return {
      id_livre: null,
      titre: null,
      description: null,
      prix_d : null,
      pdf : null,
      pdf_url : null,
      uploadValue : null
    }
  },
  methods:{

    onfileSelected(event){
      this.pdf_url = null;
      this.pdf = event.target.files[0]
      console.log(event);
    },
  

    saveBook(){
      this.pdf_url = null;
      const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`${this.pdf.name}`).put(this.pdf);
      storageRef.on(`state_changed`,snapshot=>{
          this.uploadValue = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
      }, error=>{console.log(error.message)}, ()=>{this.uploadValue =100;
        storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
          this.pdf_url = url;
        })
      })
      console.log(this.pdf_url);

      db.collection('Livres').add({
        id_livre : this.id_livre,
        titre : this.titre,
        description : this.description,
        url: this.pdf_url  
      }).then(docRef =>{ this.$router.push('/');console.log(docRef)}
      ).catch(error =>console.log(error.message))
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the download URL of a file requires an asynchronous call to the server. For this reason any code that needs the download URL must be *inside* the callback that fires when that URL is retrieved.

So something like:

```
saveBook(){
  this.pdf_url = null;
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`${this.pdf.name}`).put(this.pdf);
  storageRef.on(`state_changed`,snapshot=>{
      this.uploadValue = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
  }, error=>{console.log(error.message)}, ()=>{this.uploadValue =100;
    storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
      db.collection('Livres').add({
        id_livre : this.id_livre,
        titre : this.titre,
        description : this.description,
        url: url  
      }).then(docRef =>{ this.$router.push('/');console.log(docRef)
      }).catch(error =>console.log(error.message))
    })
  })
}
```